# Entity Framework 4: How expensive is it to create an EntityConnection?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How expensive is it to create an EF4 EntityConnection? I am creating an EF4 desktop app with SQL Compact, and the user will be able to open database files using a File Open dialog. My code then builds an EntityConnection, like this:

```
// Configure a SQL CE connection string  
var sqlCompactConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}", filePath);

// Create an Entity Connection String Builder
var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

// Configure Builder
builder.Metadata = string.Format("res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl", m_EdmName);
builder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";
builder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlCompactConnectionString;
var edmConnectionString = builder.ToString();

// Create an EDM connection
var edmConnection = new EntityConnection(edmConnectionString);
```

I have an ObjectContextFactory class that creates object contexts for Repository classes as needed.

So, here's my question: Is it better practice to build the EntityConnection once, when I initialize the factory, or should the factory build a new connection each time it creates an object context? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overhead in EF4 is from all I know minimal - please verify [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx) - basically it comes down to opening a new database connection and even that cost is small if the provider supports connection pooling (which SQL server does).

Metadata  from MetadataWorkspace is is cached globally so this will not decrease performance (that probably wasn't true in 2009 when the blog post linked to in the other post was posted).

Also connection strings from the config file (the other performance problem indicated in that blog post) are all cached in memory, so I can't see how this can negatively impact performance either.

I would definitely use a new entity connection for each unit of work.

Comment: Thanks--saves me a lot of time. Accepted and +1.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/04/06/improving-entity-framework-performance.aspx). It seems that creating a new EntityConnection for each context is an expensive operation and the source of some major performance problems. The root of these performance issues (in your case) is the creation of the connection metadata. The other performance hit mentioned in the article (getting the connection string frmo config) would not apply to you, as you are supplying your own connection string. In my opinion, you should create a single EntityConnection.

One thing to keep in mind is that according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.aspx), EntityConnection is **not guaranteed to be thread safe**. If you are going to be accessing these connections from different threads then you will run into problems, and the safest way to solve this would be to *not* reuse the EntityConnection.